# How to convert Carbon stored in surface sediments (kg/m2) to percent?

Tags: sedimentology, carbon, biogeochemistry

I need to convert organic carbon provided in kg C/m2 to percent.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Percent of what?

Comment: I mean to convert it to % without uint

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question requires some assumptions. Firstly in what is meant by kg Carbon/m2? m2 is a measure of area, not volume. So you might quote carbon deposition in kg/m2/year - and that wouldn't meaningfully translate as a percentage. Or you need information on the depth of the soil that will hold the carbon. There are [global maps](https://databasin.org/datasets/a4cb6d367eae4e52a08902874f8bfedf/) that use kg Carbon/m2 as a unit, with an assumption that it is in the top metre. So 7 kg Carbon/m2 would be equivalent to 7 kg Carbon/m3.  To convert that to a percentage you need information on the density of soils. Typical densities are 1.1 to 1.6 g/cm2, so assuming a density of 1.35 g/cm2 our 7 kg Carbon/m3 would be 0.7% Carbon. The calculation is complicated by the fact that actual soil density varies with moisture content and with organic matter - high Carbon soils are likely to have lower bulk densities, and so you shouldn't really use one density value for calculating a conversion.